# Function inside of object doesn't want to change by reference

Tags: javascript

Hay I have this code:

```
let callback2 = () => console.warn('Old one');

let props2 = {
    callback2
}

function test(props) {
    props.callback2 = () => console.warn('siema');

}

test(props2);

callback2();
```

Here is also fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4g3p9ego/

And the outcome of that code is "Old one" instead of "siema".
But functions are not Primitives and object also, so I expected outcome 'siema'.

Have you idea Why I got "Old one" message?

========== EDITED: EXTENDED EXAMPLE ===========

```
let callback2 = () => console.warn('Old one');

let moreTest = {
    moreTest: 'moreTest'
}

let props2 = {
    callback2,
    moreTestObject: moreTest
}

function test(props) {
    props.callback2 = () => console.warn('siema');
    props.moreTestObject.moreTest = 'Changed';

}

test(props2);

console.warn(moreTest)
callback2();
```

Why here I can change object? But can't change function?

I got:

> {moreTest: "Changed"}
>
> "Old one"

Expected:

> {moreTest: "Changed"}
>
> "siema"

========== SOLUTION ===========

I understand all, my confusion was caused because I didn't know that object {} always knows how to find it's props. So even I have

```
testObj = {
   inside: 'inside' // 0x123
}
```

When I call test.Obj object knows that it needs to go to 0x123. And change testObj like :

```
testObj.inside = 'outside' //0x125
```

Use it, testObj.inside and object knows to go to 0x125.

Because object has somehow to keep information where it can find it's props.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `props2.callback2()` will print new message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is because you don't replace `callback2` variable but attribute of `props` object.

```
// you create variable with 1 reference : exemple is our memory addr 0x123
let callback2 = () => console.warn('Old one');

// You copy this reference to another variable : props2 = 0x123 where 0x123 is reference from previous line.
let props2 = {
    callback2
}

function test(props) {
    let {callback2} = props;
    // You replace old reference by new one, this not impact callback2 variable, just remove 1 reference to callback2 and create new one.
    props.callback2 = () => console.warn('siema'); // Replace 0x123 reference by new one, exemple 0x456

}

test(props2);

callback2();
```

Is all about `count reference` by the `garbage collector` in JavaScript. *[Official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)*

"Complexe type" as `Object` and `Array` require possible heavy memory leak if you really clone the data when you do affection (myVar2 = myVar1).

To prevent this, Javascript copy the reference of your data (adresse in memory) instead of copying full data.

Where is can be confusing on your case.

line : `props.callback2 = () => console.warn('siema');` doesn't affect other variables who share the same memory reference. You override previous memory reference by new one on correspond to this new anonymous method `() => console.warn('siema');`

--- UPDATE 1 ---

```
let callback2 = () => console.warn('Old one');
// This create Ox123 reference in memory.
let moreTest = {
    moreTest: 'moreTest'
}

let props2 = {
    callback2,
    moreTestObject: moreTest // where ou copy Ox123 reference to moreTestObject property
}

function test(props) {
    props.callback2 = () => console.warn('siema');
    // where you edit Ox123 memory reference, is why  you impact both variable who have same reference.
    // props.moreTestObject.moreTest = 'Changed';
    // here you replace Ox123 memory reference by new one : 0x456. This will not impact moreTest original reference because you don't update Ox123 but replace by new entire reference in moreTestObject property
    props.moreTestObject = { moreTest: 'Changed'};

}

test(props2);

console.warn(moreTest)
callback2();
```

**EDIT 2**

According to your last update, i see no other choice than do something like this. Or more graceful second sample

```
//Change this to var as global variable.
var callback2 = () => console.warn('Old one');

let moreTest = {
    moreTest: 'moreTest'
}

let props2 = {
    callback2,
    moreTestObject: moreTest
}

function test(props) {
    // I see no choice than override both here.
    callback2 = props.callback2 = () => console.warn('siema');

}

test(props2);

console.warn(moreTest)
callback2();
```

More graceful :

```
let util = {
    foo : () => console.warn('Old one')
};
​
let second = {
    util
}
let third = {
    util
}
​
​
function test(props) {
     props.foo = () => console.warn('siema');
}
​
test(util);
util.foo(); // Output `siema`
second.util.foo(); // Output `siema`
third.util.foo(); // Output `siema`
```

Comment: So why this " props.moreTestObject.moreTest = 'Changed';" in Extended example modify object?

Comment: @PatrykJanik i have update my example, is because you don't override reference, you override one property of the reference who impact original 1. i hope my new sample will be more clear. Let me know if no.

Comment: I still don't know why: console.warn(moreTest) gives me "Changed" and callback gives me "Old one"

Comment: Updated question with what I got what I expected.

Comment: i have updated my answer according to what you expect.

Comment: I understand all, my confusion was caused because I didn't know that object {} always knows how to find it's props. So even I have testObj = {
inside: 'inside' // 0x123
} When I call test.Obj object knows that it needs to go to 0x123. And change testObj like : testObj.inside = 'outside' //0x125. Use it testObj.inside and object know to goes 0x125. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i hope is more clear now :) i have try my best to be clearest as possible but i am not sure if i have rich this goal. Happy coding @PatrykJanik

Answer (score 2):

> But functions are not Primitives

That doesn't matter. You never try to modify a function.

Objects are not primitives either.

First, you create an object and assign your original `callback2` function to the `callback2` property.

> ```
> let props2 = {
>     callback2
> }
> ```

Then you copy the value of `props2` (which is a reference to that object) to the function argument.

> ```
> test(props2);
> ```

Then you overwrite the value of the `callback2` property of that object with a new value (a function that calls `console.warn`).

> ```
> props.callback2 = () => console.warn('siema');
> ```

Then you call:

> ```
> callback2();
> ```

… but that's a variable that **still** has a value that is a reference to the original function. You never change that.

> Why here I can change object? But can't change function?

`x = y` changes *the thing on the left*.

Here:

> ```
> props.moreTestObject.moreTest = 'Changed';
> ```

The thing on the left is the `moreTest` property of the object referenced by `props.moreTestObject`.

Here:

> ```
> props.callback2 = () => console.warn('siema');
> ```

The thing on the left is the `callback2` property of the object referenced by `props`.

The thing on the left is not a function.

The value its holds before you assign it a new value is a reference to a function, but that doesn't matter because you are overwriting that value with a new one.

The value of the `callback2` variable is also a reference to that function (which is referenced by the old value of `props.callback2`) but that doesn't matter because you aren't changing the value of the `callback2` variable.

Comment: Well explain, @Patryk Janik is confusing about impact of change reference by another one. If i copy reference to another object then modify this other object, this will impact original reference ? answser is no but i am not sure if my explication is clear.

Answer (score 1):

What you do inside a function will not remain outside a function. You need to return props

```
function test(props) {
  props.callback2 = () => console.warn('siema');
  return props
}

props2 = test(props2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Have you idea Why I got "Old one" message?

Accessibility of `let {callback2} = props;` inside `test()` is limited to the block in which it got initialized, i.e. `test` function.

Outside test, it will retain the old bindings of

```
let callback2 = () => console.warn('Old one');
```

Remove `let` from `let {callback2} = props;` to set new reference that stays outside  as well..

```
function test(props) {
    callback2 = props.callback2;

    // callback2 = () => console.warn('siema');
    props.callback2 = () => console.warn('siema');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you call `props2.callback2()` it will output `siema`.